# enable_if on conversion constructor (static cast, is_base_of)

Tags: c++, type-conversion, enable-if, static-cast

I am working on an implementation of a shared pointer. (using C++17, in case it matters)

The only issue is the conversion constructor. I want to be able to static cast a smart_ptr to a smart_ptr of base type.

```
template<typename U>
inline smart_ptr(const smart_ptr<U>& rhs)
{
    ...
}
```

It works, but it will also try to cast a smart_ptr to a smart_ptr of any other type. For example, if I have an overloaded function that can take different kinds of smart_ptr's of unrelated type, I get a compiler error about ambiguous overload. So, I only want the conversion from smart_ptr -> smart_ptr if U is a derived class of T.

This looks like it should work. It compiles, but it does the opposite. It prevents the valid static upcasts from working, but still allows the casting to unrelated types:

```
template<typename U>
inline local_shared_ptr(typename enable_if<is_base_of<T,U>::value, const  local_shared_ptr<U>&>::type rhs)
{
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Got it working, thanks for the help. I choose jarod's solution, since I find `template <typename U, enable_if_t<is_base_of<T,U>::value, int> = 0>` the most concise. I didn't realize SFINAE could be that concise.

Also, since it was mentioned by Nathan:

Funnily enough, one of the issues I encountered is that I expected the template copy constructor to be called when the right-hand-side is the same type. Apparently, the compiler doesn't consider it an implementation of the copy constructor, and instead the auto-generated copy constructor was being called instead. Same issue for the move constructor and operator=. Not sure if that's a bug with MSVC2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`U` is non deducible with

```
template<typename U>
local_shared_ptr(enable_if_t<is_base_of<T,U>::value, const  local_shared_ptr<U>&> rhs)
{
// ...
}
```

And as it is a constructor, you even cannot provide template explicitly.
So that constructor is useless.

You can use instead:

- Default parameter (the most similar to your attempt IMO):

  ```
  template <typename U>
  local_shared_ptr(const local_shared_ptr<U>& rhs, enable_if_t<is_base_of<T,U>::value, int> = 0)
  {
  // ...
  }
  ```
- default template parameter (preferred way):

  ```
  template <typename U, enable_if_t<is_base_of<T,U>::value, int> = 0>
  local_shared_ptr(const local_shared_ptr<U>& rhs)
  {
  // ...
  }
  ```

And as you use constructor, you cannot use return value.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `enable_if` in the template parameter list like

```
template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, U>, bool> = true>
inline smart_ptr(const smart_ptr<U>& rhs)
{

}
```

And now this will only be called if `U` is `T`, or is derived from `T`.  If you don't want to use this if `U == T` then you can use

```
template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, U> && !std::is_same_v<T, U>, bool> = true>
inline smart_ptr(const smart_ptr<U>& rhs)
{

}
```